# Can I have two visas (Jobseeker and Dependent) both for Germany?

Tags: germany, dependent-visa

Myself (Non EU citizen) applied for Jobseeker visa for Germany which is under process and meantime my wife got job offer from German employer.

I am wondering if I should go for Dependent visa or not ?
Is it allowed to have both Jobseeker and Dependent visa ?

Comment: If you're allowed to work with the dependent visa it would probably make more sense to get that, as it will probably be much easier to get.

Comment: Ys its allowed to work on dependent visa